# Animation transitions won't work

Tags: animation

I downloaded an animated spider that comes with its own animations. I put the idle and walk animations in the controller. The default idle works fine but it won't transition to walk. I have other characters in my scene that transition with no problem. The only difference is that the other characters animations are separate from the character and the spider's animations are attached to the spider. I have been looking for any tutorial on the attached animations but can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please walk us through the precise, detailed steps we need to follow to reproduce the problem you're seeing. Without understanding the exact situation you're in, we'll have a very hard time explaining how to get out of it.

Comment: I don't know how much more I can say. Go to asset store, download Fantasy Spider. As I said I duplicated the idle and walk animations, put them in my animation controller, attached that to my spider along with a animator, and a script to control the transitions when I press a key. In the animation controller window you can see the transition but the transition doesn't happen in the game.